# ocean physics and simulation

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation, ocean-simulation

do you have some recommendations on how to create a shot in which a monster breaches through the ocean's surface? Kind of like in the Gozilla Movies.
I looked at the ocean modifier but what I need is a full-on collision simulation.
Here is an example video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwdld-51PRg

Comment: any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: For that, you will need simulations. In my experience, Mantaflow is just not up to the task. You might want to try Flip fluids but I do not have any experience with that so can not tell you at all whether it will manage this. And could you please add the update as a new question? That way everything is separated and it is easier to help you.